# How to know which overlayitem is being tapped?

Tags: android

currently I used a map view and placed some overlay items in them

I overiden the onTap function in ItemizedOverlay so that when user tap on the markers icons on the map, some action will perform.

However, I don't know how to know which marker is being tapped so that the related data of the item will be displayed in the screen. How can I do that?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

The `onTap()` method receives the index of the item being tapped. Since you are the one who gave the `ItemizedOverlay` the items in a sequence in the first place, your code should be able to determine which item appears at that index, such as via `get()` on an `ArrayList` of `OverlayItems`.

[This sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk/) demonstrates the technique.

Comment: Thanks! :D I didn't know that I can get the index!!